# Using recursion and memoization with collatz

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization, collatz

Unchecked Theorem (Collatz): all the numbers to which this sequence of functions is applied, end in 1.Of the numbers between 1 and 1000000, to which corresponds the longest sequence?

How can I use memoization so the operation doesn't take so long and know the largest sequence from 1-1,000,000 ?

```
def Collatz(n, arr):
    arr.append(n)
    if n == 1:
        return arr
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        return Collatz(n / 2, arr)
    elif n % 2 == 1:
        return Collatz((3 * n) + 1, arr)
```

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify what exactly you're asking? Please correct me if it's obvious and I'm just reading it wrong or something.

Comment: what I am asking is how can I use memorization and know the largest sequence with this code.

Comment: @briancolor Oh, got it. I would recommend editing your question to ask that explicitly because it isn't quite clear. Also, as your question currently stands, it sounds like you are asking "Of the numbers between 1 and 1000000, to which corresponds the longest sequence?". Consider removing that problem statement entirely or contextualizing it in a way that it doesn't sound like it's what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memoization gives you a mapping (which, in Python, is usually a `dict`) from an
input to an output -- a shortcut that avoids repeating a computation. For
collatz, the input is an integer `n` -- notice that `arr` is not part of the input as far as the Conjecture is concerned.

Since you want to find the longest sequence, it would make sense to make the
mapping be from `n` to a list -- the kind of sequence, `arr`, that your original
code returns.  (See below for a faster way -- it turns out that memoizing just
the length of the sequences is much much faster.)

Nevertheless, let's pursue the original idea and see what your code would look like with memoization:
The dict used for memoization should have *keys* which are integers, `n`, and *values* which are lists like `arr`:

```
def collatz(n, seen={}):
    if n not in seen:                                     # (1)
        if n == 1:                                        # (2)
            seen[n] = [n]
        elif n % 2 == 0:
            seen[n] = collatz(n // 2, seen) + [n]         # (3)
        elif n % 2 == 1:
            seen[n] = collatz((3 * n) + 1, seen) + [n]
    return seen[n]
```

1. Take care of the memoization right away. If `n` is in the dict `seen`, 
   we can skip the body of the `if-statement` and just return `seen[n]`.

   I chose to place the `return seen[n]` at the end so it is utterly clear that
   all calls to `collatz` end at this return statement.
2. Take care of the base case.
3. Notice that if `collatz` always returns `seen[n]` for some `n`, and if `seen[n]` is always a list, then  `collatz(n // 2, seen) + [n]` will be the list returned by `collatz` with `n` appended to the end of the list. (For example, in Python `[1] + [2]` is `[1, 2]`).

---

```
def collatz(n, seen={}):
    if n not in seen:                                    
        if n == 1:                                       
            seen[n] = [n]
        elif n % 2 == 0:
            seen[n] = collatz(n // 2, seen) + [n]        
        elif n % 2 == 1:
            seen[n] = collatz((3 * n) + 1, seen) + [n]
    return seen[n]

seen = {}
n, arr = None, []
for i in range(1, 10**6):
    seq = collatz(i, seen)
    if len(seq) > len(arr):
        n = i
        arr = seq

print('longest sequence: collatz({}) = {}'.format(n, arr))
```

returns

```
longest sequence: collatz(837799) = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 5, 10, 20, 40, 80, 160, 53, 106, 35, 70, 23, 46, 92, 184, 61, 122, 244, 488, 976, 325, 650, 1300, 433, 866, 1732, 577, 1154, 2308, 4616, 9232, 3077, 6154, 2051, 4102, 1367, 2734, 911, 1822, 3644, 7288, 2429, 4858, 1619, 3238, 1079, 2158, 719, 1438, 479, 958, 319, 638, 1276, 425, 850, 283, 566, 1132, 377, 754, 251, 502, 167, 334, 668, 1336, 445, 890, 1780, 593, 1186, 395, 790, 263, 526, 175, 350, 700, 233, 466, 155, 310, 103, 206, 412, 137, 274, 91, 182, 364, 121, 242, 484, 161, 322, 107, 214, 71, 142, 47, 94, 31, 62, 124, 41, 82, 164, 328, 109, 218, 436, 145, 290, 580, 1160, 2320, 773, 1546, 515, 1030, 343, 686, 1372, 457, 914, 1828, 3656, 7312, 2437, 4874, 9748, 19496, 38992, 12997, 25994, 51988, 17329, 34658, 69316, 23105, 46210, 92420, 184840, 61613, 123226, 41075, 82150, 27383, 54766, 109532, 219064, 73021, 146042, 292084, 97361, 194722, 64907, 129814, 43271, 86542, 28847, 57694, 115388, 230776, 76925, 153850, 307700, 615400, 205133, 410266, 820532, 1641064, 547021, 1094042, 2188084, 729361, 1458722, 2917444, 972481, 1944962, 3889924, 1296641, 2593282, 864427, 1728854, 3457708, 1152569, 2305138, 768379, 1536758, 3073516, 1024505, 2049010, 683003, 1366006, 455335, 910670, 1821340, 3642680, 7285360, 2428453, 4856906, 9713812, 3237937, 6475874, 12951748, 25903496, 51806992, 17268997, 34537994, 69075988, 23025329, 46050658, 15350219, 30700438, 10233479, 20466958, 6822319, 13644638, 27289276, 9096425, 18192850, 6064283, 12128566, 4042855, 8085710, 16171420, 5390473, 10780946, 21561892, 7187297, 14374594, 28749188, 57498376, 114996752, 229993504, 76664501, 153329002, 51109667, 102219334, 34073111, 68146222, 22715407, 45430814, 90861628, 30287209, 60574418, 121148836, 40382945, 80765890, 26921963, 53843926, 17947975, 35895950, 71791900, 23930633, 47861266, 15953755, 31907510, 63815020, 21271673, 42543346, 85086692, 170173384, 56724461, 113448922, 37816307, 75632614, 25210871, 50421742, 16807247, 33614494, 11204831, 22409662, 7469887, 14939774, 29879548, 9959849, 19919698, 6639899, 13279798, 26559596, 53119192, 17706397, 35412794, 70825588, 23608529, 47217058, 15739019, 31478038, 10492679, 20985358, 6995119, 13990238, 27980476, 9326825, 18653650, 6217883, 12435766, 4145255, 8290510, 2763503, 5527006, 1842335, 3684670, 1228223, 2456446, 4912892, 9825784, 3275261, 6550522, 2183507, 4367014, 1455671, 2911342, 5822684, 11645368, 3881789, 7763578, 2587859, 5175718, 1725239, 3450478, 6900956, 13801912, 4600637, 9201274, 3067091, 6134182, 2044727, 4089454, 1363151, 2726302, 908767, 1817534, 3635068, 1211689, 2423378, 4846756, 1615585, 3231170, 6462340, 2154113, 4308226, 1436075, 2872150, 957383, 1914766, 638255, 1276510, 2553020, 5106040, 1702013, 3404026, 6808052, 13616104, 4538701, 9077402, 18154804, 6051601, 12103202, 24206404, 48412808, 96825616, 32275205, 64550410, 21516803, 43033606, 14344535, 28689070, 9563023, 19126046, 38252092, 12750697, 25501394, 51002788, 102005576, 204011152, 68003717, 136007434, 272014868, 544029736, 181343245, 362686490, 725372980, 241790993, 483581986, 161193995, 322387990, 107462663, 214925326, 71641775, 143283550, 47761183, 95522366, 191044732, 382089464, 764178928, 254726309, 509452618, 1018905236, 2037810472, 679270157, 1358540314, 452846771, 905693542, 301897847, 603795694, 201265231, 402530462, 805060924, 268353641, 536707282, 178902427, 357804854, 715609708, 238536569, 477073138, 159024379, 318048758, 636097516, 212032505, 424065010, 141355003, 282710006, 565420012, 188473337, 376946674, 125648891, 251297782, 83765927, 167531854, 335063708, 670127416, 223375805, 446751610, 148917203, 297834406, 99278135, 198556270, 66185423, 132370846, 44123615, 88247230, 29415743, 58831486, 19610495, 39220990, 13073663, 26147326, 52294652, 104589304, 34863101, 69726202, 23242067, 46484134, 92968268, 185936536, 371873072, 743746144, 1487492288, 2974984576, 991661525, 1983323050, 661107683, 1322215366, 440738455, 881476910, 1762953820, 587651273, 1175302546, 391767515, 783535030, 261178343, 522356686, 174118895, 348237790, 116079263, 232158526, 77386175, 154772350, 51590783, 103181566, 34393855, 68787710, 137575420, 45858473, 91716946, 30572315, 61144630, 20381543, 40763086, 13587695, 27175390, 9058463, 18116926, 6038975, 12077950, 4025983, 8051966, 16103932, 5367977, 10735954, 3578651, 7157302, 2385767, 4771534, 1590511, 3181022, 6362044, 2120681, 4241362, 1413787, 2827574, 5655148, 1885049, 3770098, 1256699, 2513398, 837799]
```

The computation takes about 24 seconds (on my computer).

---

**The faster way:**

A possible way to improve this code is to reduce the amount of repetition in
`seen`. This dict of lists can take up a lot of memory since there are a lot of
keys and the lists can get rather long. Moreover, *there is a lot of repetition*
in the lists.

What if we only keep the length of the sequence, and not the sequence itself? 
Even though we want to find the longest sequence,
once we know the `n` associated with longest sequence, regenerating the sequence is pretty quick.

Now the code would look like this:

```
def collatz(n, seen={}):
    if n not in seen:                          
        if n == 1:                             
            seen[n] = 1
        elif n % 2 == 0:
            seen[n] = collatz(n // 2, seen) + 1
        elif n % 2 == 1:
            seen[n] = collatz((3 * n) + 1, seen) + 1
    return seen[n]
```

Now `seen` is a map from values of `n` to integer lengths of sequences. 
The value of `n` associated with the longest sequence can now be found this way:

```
def collatz(n, seen={}):
    if n not in seen:                          
        if n == 1:                             
            seen[n] = 1
        elif n % 2 == 0:
            seen[n] = collatz(n // 2, seen) + 1
        elif n % 2 == 1:
            seen[n] = collatz((3 * n) + 1, seen) + 1
    return seen[n]

seen = {}
n, max_len = None, 0
for i in range(1, 10**6):
    length = collatz(i, seen)
    if length > max_len:
        n = i
        max_len = length

def show_collatz(n):
    if n == 1:                             
        result = [1]
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        result = show_collatz(n // 2) + [n]
    elif n % 2 == 1:
        result = show_collatz((3 * n) + 1) + [n]
    return result

print('longest sequence: collatz({}) = {}'.format(n, show_collatz(n)))
```

You'll find this version of the code runs much quicker (it takes about 2 seconds instead of 24 seconds.)

---

Finally, having two versions of the code (`collatz` and `show_collatz`) which do almost the same thing violates the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (Don't Repeat Yourself). We can fix that problem by adding a parameter `return_length` to handle both cases. Happily, the similarity of the two functions is so strong, the change is minimal:

```
def collatz(n, seen={}, return_length=True):
    if return_length:
        x = 1
    else:
        x = [n]
    if n not in seen:                          
        if n == 1:                             
            seen[n] = x
        elif n % 2 == 0:
            seen[n] = collatz(n // 2, seen, return_length) + x
        elif n % 2 == 1:
            seen[n] = collatz((3 * n) + 1, seen, return_length) + x
    return seen[n]

seen = {}
n, max_len = None, 0
for i in range(1, 10**6):
    length = collatz(i, seen)
    if length > max_len:
        n = i
        max_len = length

print('longest sequence: collatz({}) = {}'.format(n, collatz(n, return_length=False)))
```